can I use Eth base for apecoin transaction fees?
I have apecoin worth $12 on exodus wallet it saids i need eth to send to external wallet so I’m wondering if i can use Ethereum (base) for gas fee instead of Ethereum (eth)

If you want to transfer APE ERC-20 from your wallet on Ethereum Mainnet, you need ETH to pay for the gas fees. If you have your ERC-20 on Base network and sending APE on the Base network to another wallet on Base, you can use BASE for gas fees.
Otherwise, if you have your APE on ETH mainnet:
For transactions on ETH Mainnet, you need ETH for gas fees.
